# How to call function in LLVM

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I would like to ask you on the proper way to call/bind own c++ function into LLVM.

I have coded simple function:

```
void writeSomething() {
    std::cout << "Awesome" << std::endl;
}
```

In LLVM I am trying to register the function. I have created the external linkage to it.

```
      // Void type
llvm::FunctionType* fccType =
        llvm::FunctionType::get(
            llvm::Type::getVoidTy(getGlobalContext()), false
        );

// External - c++
Function *fcc = (Function*) module->getOrInsertFunction("writeSomething",
        fccType
        );

// Call
std::vector<Value*> emptyArgs;
CallInst::Create(fcc, makeArrayRef(emptyArgs));
```

LLVM Output for just calling this function is 
( // comments are mine input how do I understand the output )

```
// External linkage
declare void @writeSomething()

define internal void @main() {
entry:
  // Call my function
  call void @writeSomething()
  ret void
}
```

The program ends with message: *LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'writeSomething' which could not be resolved!*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to [C++ name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), the name of that function is actually something like `_Z14writeSomethingv` - C++ supports overloading by encoding type information in the function name.

You can disable this by declaring the function as `extern "C" void writeSomething() { ... }`, or figure out what it should be called under your compiler's name mangling scheme and use that.